# Ensure object includes dynamic key

Tags: typescript

I use the following code to validate that only existing keys are accessed on a specific object:

```
function prop<O, K extends keyof O>(key: K, obj: O) {
    return obj[key];
}
```

This works well enough and will work as expected when using the following code:

```
const obj = { foo: 'bar' };
prop('foo', obj); // ok
prop('bar', obj); // error
```

However, I would like to restructure my code to work as follows:

```
const obj = { foo: 'bar' };
prop('foo')(obj); // should be ok
prop('bar')(obj); // should error
```

My first idea was to just restructure the function as follows:

```
function prop<O, K extends keyof O>(key: K) {
    return function inner(obj: O) {
        return obj[key];
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work and yields the following error:

> Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to the parameter of type
>   'never'.

This makes sense to me, since the object is not available when the key is validated.

Hence, I am aiming to flip the validation logic from "check that the key is present in the object" to "check that the object includes the key" as soon as the object is passed into the second function and error on the type validation of the object if it doesn't, with no other constraints at this specific point.

It feels like this should be possible with TypeScript, but I have not found a way to do this with a completely dynamic key and object, with the only condition for the object being that the given key is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `O` is not yet set, you can't have it as a parameter on the first function call (no place you can infer it from). You could of course specify it manually but that is not ideal.

Another option is to spcify the `O` parameter on the second function. The first call will specify `K` (as beeing a key, any key). The second call will specify `O` with the constraint that `O` must have a key `K` with any type.

```
function prop<K extends keyof any>(key: K) {
    return function inner<O extends Record<K, any>>(obj: O) : O[K]{
        return obj[key];
    }
}

const obj = { foo: 'bar' };
prop('foo')(obj); // be ok, returns string
prop('bar')(obj); // is error
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I like that it also gives me the option of specifying a type of the key if needed (e.g. only strings and symbols).

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy manually specifying the generic, then the following would work:

```
function prop<O>(key: keyof O) {
    return function inner(obj: O) {
        return obj[key];
    }
}

prop<{ prop: string }>('prop')({ prop: 'test'}) // compiles
prop<{ prop: string }>('prop')({ wrong: 'test'}) // error
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind specifying the generic if there is no other solution (though without would obv be preferred), but if I'm seeing this correctly, this would also error on something like `prop<{ prop: string }>('prop')({ prop: 'test', wrong: 'test'})`, since the extra key isn't part of the generic?

Comment: @mvuajua yeah you would get an error in such a case because of excess property checks. also the return type will be a union of all possible values of `O`, again not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Put the type parameter in the beginning:

```
const prop = <T>(property: keyof T) =>
  (source: T) =>
    source[property];
```

For maximum type safety, provide the type parameter when calling `prop`:

```
const prop = <T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(property: K) =>
  (source: T): T[K] =>
    source[property];

prop<typeof obj>('foo')(obj); // $ExpectType string
prop<typeof obj>('bar')(obj); // $ExpectError
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok for you?

```
export function hasProp<T extends object>(obj: T, prop: string): boolean {
        return (obj as any)[prop] !== undefined;
    }
```

Also you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this with my specific use case (not having the prop and obj in the same function call), can you give an example?